# GetShopped Ecommerce: hide checkout form from customer until shipping country selected

Tags: e-commerce, plugin-wp-e-commerce

I am using Wordpress Ecommerce by GetShopped, and on the checkout page there is a part where the user selects their country.

By default, not all the available delivery options are displayed until the user selects their country or the Calculate button.

The problem is, the customers **assume** that there is no delivery available (as its hidden until they select the country or click Calculate).

How can I hide the rest of the form from the customer (therefore requiring them to select their country), before displaying the remainder of the form?

Comment: Hi - this sounds like something more appropriate for the GetShopped forums than here.

Comment: Well, to be fair, this question on the GetShopped forums will languish, gathering dust until the OP gets frustrated enough to switch to WooCommerce.

Comment: please, please pretty please , make a better title for this question

Comment: I rewrote a wpec checkout template once, and it was, quite frankly, a complete nightmare.  There is a lot of javascript running around that you're going to have to deal with to avoid hacking the plugin directly.  That said, for your specific issue, after having dumped hundreds of hours into wpec, I would recommend writing your own template forcing the customer to select their country first and then redirect them to the wpec checkout by running the submit_change_country() js function found in wpsc-core/js/wp-e-commerce.js.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a question for the GetShopped Forums, as #1, the forums are fairly active (and the company also offers premium support, which you may/may not have), #2 it's a customization question specific to their code.

If you want to post some code and the template files involved, maybe someone can help.

Or, possibly add some text in that template to say that delivery options are available once a country, etc., is selected.

Comment: I would really disagree with #1 songdog.  FWIW, having purchased premium support from them I was still unable to post on the premium forum and never received a response from them via email, I think their commitment to the product is non-existent.  Last paragraph about adding text is probably the way to go though.

Comment: You pay your money and you take your chances. People on WPSE are not obligated to help when the company won't. But some can and will. It's been discussed before: http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1233/dealing-with-woothemes-commerce-questions/1246

Answer (score 0):

Since I didnt see the code, i can suggest this in css,javascript:

Try to find the id of the div which you want to display all time.

now add inline style to div with display:block

This would display everytime, otherwise u can add style through javascript when user lands to that page.

Ex:

```
<div id="delivery">
...
</div>
```

now you have to change that code to

```
<div id="delivery" style="display:block">
...
</div>
```

but however this is not always reliable, but if you can post the php code we could help you